# how to do `var self = this` inside es6 class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am running the below code in nodejs

```
this.x = 'global x';
class Point {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
var obj = new Point(1);
obj.toString();// 1 as expected
var a = obj.toString;// Here I can do something like var a = obj.toString.bind(obj); to get rid of the situation. But I am curious to know how can we write `var self = this`;
a();// TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

`a();` throws the error.
How can we do like `var self = this;` as we used to do in `es5` to prevent such a situation?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your first line this.x = 'global x'; ?

Comment: @Roumelis  I was expecting `a()` will run in global code and `toString()` is returning `this.x` so `a()` will return `global x`

Comment: You are adding x in window on purpose then?

Comment: Yea I thought something like that.  But this will be my another query what happens in nodejs when we write `this.x` globally. Code runs fine when we write globally `this.x = 'something'`. `get(this.x);` outputs `'something'`

Comment: You are doing it exactly the same way. Nothing changed in that regard in ES6 (except you also have arrow functions). It's unclear to me how you would use `var self = this` without classes to begin with...

Comment: Never mix lexical and contextual scopes in JS. Use .bind or arrow functions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> How can we do like `var self = this;` as we used to do in ES5?

You can do it exactly like you did in ES5 - ES6 is completely backward-compatible after all:

```
class Point {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
        var self = this;
        this.toString = function() {
            return self.x;
        };
    }
}
```

However, that's really not idiomatic ES6 (not talking about `const` instead of `var`). You'd rather use an arrow function that has a lexical-scoped `this`, so that you can avoid this `self` variable completely:

```
class Point {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
        this.toString = () => {
            return this.x;
        };
    }
}
```

(which could even be shortened to `this.toString = () => this.x;`)

Comment: if I put this code `this.toString = function() {  return self.x; };` out of constructor like this  `toString() {  return self.x; };` as we can do this, In this case self is `undefined` and throw error

Comment: @intekhab: Yes of course it is - `self` is a variable scoped to the constructor. As I said, it works just like in ES5. The new ES6 `class` syntax introduces hardly anything new but the *syntax*.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to create all your class methods inside the constructor as Bergi suggests (which seems ugly to me) then you can [enable ES7 features](http://jamesknelson.com/unlocking-decorators-and-other-es7-features-with-webpack-and-babel) and define your method using arrow syntax:

```
class Point 
{
    constructor(x) 
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    toString = () =>  
    {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

This has the same effect as saying:

```
constructor(x)
{
    this.toString = this.toString.bind(this);
}
```

But it still doesn't allow you to access the dynamic *this* and the lexical *this* (*self*) in the same function. So this is **not** a complete answer.

I hope someone can edit this answer to show how we can access both types of *this* in a class method without defining every method in the class constructor.

Comment: Well, this still does create all your methods inside the constructor (and is just as ugly), only it uses an experimental syntax for it.